# Microphone Access for WKWebView or WebView

Tags: swift, uiwebview, wkwebview, microphone

I have a basic iOS application written in Swift which loads an HTML5 website within WKWebView. I'm wondering if it's possible to access the microphone to record audio? I have requested permission explicitly to the user in the normal fashion for a native application, but am still unable to access the microphone.

Here's a snippet of what I've got:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    var session: AVAudioSession!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        if (session.responds(to: #selector(AVAudioSession.requestRecordPermission(_:)))) {
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(granted: Bool)-> Void in
                if granted {
                    print("granted")

                    do {
                        try self.session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
                        try self.session.setActive(true)
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("Couldn't set Audio session category")
                    }
                } else{
                    print("not granted")
                }
            })
        }

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.somewebsite.com/")
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 0.0)
        self.webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
javaScriptEnable = true
```